# React/JSX Error: Any use of a keyed object should be wrapped in React.addons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

The whole error:

> "Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique \"key\" prop. Check the render method of RenderArray"

The code:

```
/* jshint esnext: true */

class RenderArray extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {myArray : ""};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state.myArray);
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    this.setState({
      myArray: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
    });
  }


  render () {

    showEl = this.state.myArray.map(function(i) {
      return <li>{i}</li>;
    })


    return (
       <div className="jumbotron container">
          <ul>
            {showEl}
          </ul>
       </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope, this will help

```
 showEl = this.state.myArray.map(function(i) {
  return <li key={i}>{i}</li>;
})
```

Also, examine this link  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children

Comment: I am giving you the right answer because your answer is correct as the other 2 but you were the first answering. Thanks. And thanks to the other 2 guys.

Answer (score 3):

For each repeated element, react wants a unique key. So in your case, something like:

```
showEl = this.state.myArray.map(function(i) {
  return <li key={i}>{i}</li>;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not an error, it's a warning, and it's telling you precisely what to do. Add a `key` prop on the child of your array.

```
showEl = this.state.myArray.map(function(i) {
  return <li key={i}>{i}</li>;
})
```

Read about [reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html)  when you get a chance.